# drupal 6 to 7 site upgrade using drush_sup - how to download compatible drupal 7 modules

Tags: drush, updating

I used [drush_sup](http://drupal.org/project/drush_sup) to upgrade my drupal 6 to 7 site. everything went smooth except the drupal 7 modules were not downloaded to the upgraded website.

During the upgrade process it did list the installed D6 modules, and the recommended D7 counterparts. I'm not sure what caused it to skip downloading it or maybe it just doesn't?

Thanks, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would run through the site upgrade process with the `--prompt-all` flag set to see if anything strange appears.

`drush drush_sup` will upgrade core and find *good* candidates for contrib modules, I think it'll even accept dev releases, but with a warning.

You could also pass in `--auto` to the command which will just do the defaults.

Source: http://drupalcode.org/project/drush_sup.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/README.txt