# Upgrading a site

Tags: 7, drush, upgrading

I am attempting to upgrade one of my sites from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7. I have downloaded and made Drush executable. I've also install the Drush site-upgrade command. The problem I'm having is understanding the steps or the process of aliases. I really need someone to explain it to me in layman's terms as I am just learning all of this. I've tried several different configurations and still can't seem to get it to work. So after some digging around within Drush I have also noticed when I do the drush st command I get this (posted below)

PHP configuration     :  /home/user/drush/php.ini /home/user/drush/php.ini 
 Drush version         :  5.9
 Drush configuration   :
 Drush alias files     :  /home/user/.drush/cm.aliases.drushrc.php

Which I'm thinking is wrong, I shouldn't have 2 php.ini files show up for my PHP configuration should I?
I should mention I have a multi domain site.
I'm guessing I need to fix this first before I figure out the aliases issue, but I have posted what I put in the .drush folder as my cm.aliaes.drushrc.php file

```
$aliases['test'] = array(
  'root' => '/public_html/folder-of-domain-to-update',
  'uri' => 'localhost',
);
```

If I go to the /home folder and run the command `drush sa`, I get:

```
@cm
@cm.test
@none
```

If I go to the /home/user/public_html/folder-of-domain-to-update and run the command `drush sa`, I get:

```
@cm
@cm.test
@none
@self
default
```

When I run the command `drush sup` at the /home/user/public_html/folder-of-domain-to-update level I get this:

> No target argument specified. To perform the site upgrade, define an alias record for the target site.

If someone could give me some direction or help I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Migrate module](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) for this purpose.

> The migrate module provides a flexible framework for migrating content into Drupal from other sources (e.g., when converting a web site from another CMS to Drupal). Out-of-the-box, support for creating core Drupal objects such as nodes, users, files, terms, and comments are included - it can easily be extended for migrating other kinds of content. Content is imported and rolled back using a bundled web interface (Migrate UI module) or included Drush commands (strongly recommended).

For more details you could go through the README.txt of this module.

Comment: Hi Nitesh, the migrate module..., I'll read about it to see if I can figure it out. It looks like to upgrade a site from Drupal 6 to 7 I also need three other modules to make it work... Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you,

For Upgrading from D6 to D7 you need to use [Drush Site Upgrade](https://drupal.org/project/drush_sup) module.
You can go through **[Use Drush to Upgrade from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/50880/drupal-6-to-7-site-upgrade-using-drush-sup-how-to-download-compatible-drupal-7)**

You can also refer [Use Drush to Upgrade from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7](http://www.acquia.com/blog/use-drush-upgrade-drupal-6-drupal-7)

Comment: Yea, I have read through those links no help really... I really need someone to explain aliases so that a complete novice (myself) can understand it...                          Thank you for responding though, I will look through the links again and see if something "clicks" in my brain...